# Throw exception if more than one file in a folder

Tags: c#, file, count

Below is the snippet of code I'm using to count the files in a folder (just files, not additional folders).  If there is more than one file in this folder I need to throw an exception.

```
private bool CheckCondition2(String FolderName)
{
    bool ConditionPassed = false;

    System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderName);
    int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;

    ConditionPassed = (count > 1);

    return ConditionPassed;
}
```

I then call it in main with:

```
if (!CheckCondition2(SourceFolder))
{
    CanCopy = false;
    throw new Exception("More than one mark-off file.");
}
```

Currently when I test it, it tells me there is more than one file in the directory despite there only being one.  What have I done wrong in my code?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Have you considered debugging to follow the history of your `ConditionPassed` variable?

Comment: @J.Steen: Write that as an answer and show the correct way.

Answer (score 4):

In your method, you return `true` if there are more than one files.

In your if-statement, you check for `false`, however. You seem to have mixed these up a little.

It's always a good idea to debug your code and follow the value as it changes to see if you've got any logic-errors. A more automatic and reliable way to do this is, of course, writing a unit test.

You could switch the condition in your method, to be

```
ConditionPassed = (count <= 1);
```

That way, it means that the method would return `true` when you're in a 'correct' state. You could instead change the if-statement to read

```
if (CheckCondition2(SourceFolder))
```

Either would probably work for you. In the latter example, I would also suggest changing the name of the method to something like `HasMoreThanOneFile` to make it abundantly obvious what it does.

Comment: Thanks for clearing a few things up for me.  You are right, I got confused.  I adjusted my code and it seems to now be working.  Thank you.

Comment: Great and you're welcome. Don't forget to mark an acceptable answer using the tickmark under the answer's vote-counter to the left. =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ConditionPassed = (count <= 1); //check should pass if there is at most one file
```

Answer (score 0):

Either change the condition

```
ConditionPassed = (count <= 1);
```

or the if statement

```
if (CheckCondition2(SourceFolder)))
```

I presume your success scenario is to be at most 1 files in the source folder

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a bool, why not try...

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(FolderName);
int count = dir.GetFiles().Length;

if (count > 1)
{
    throw new Exception("More than one mark-off file.");
}
else
{
    // Something else
}
```

Its a bit neater code (Sorry the OCD is kicking in!)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a flaw in your logic. ConditionPassed = (count > 1) should be  ConditionPassed = (count <=1). Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try debugging your code.
[image]

It just worked after making a small change in the if statement, it should have been `if (CheckCondition2(SourceFolder))`

Try updating name of the function to avoid confusion.

Comment: If you need to change any part of the code, it doesn't, per se, work. ;) With the naming of the method, it's probably that the intention is to return `true`, since "passed" has a positive connotation. =)